# C#: How to statically get property attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

I am looking for an elegant way of statically referencing a property attribute in C#. To give you an example, say I have this class:

```
public class A
{
    [Attribute(Name="myAttributeName")]
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I see the attribute as quite similar to a static member of a class, so in my mind, there should be an easy way to access the attribute from outside the class; e.g. through a similar operator to `typeof` or `nameof` (but it would return a list of attributes, since there may be multiple attributes to fetch). The way I would like to use this operator is as follows:

```
public class B
{
    // Through an attribute definition
    [Attribute2(attrof(A.Property1))]
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    // In a method
    public void method()
    {
        var attrs = attrof(A.property1);
    }
}
```

I think I have found one way to make it work with two parameters like the example below - at least for the method invocation. Passing variables to attributes doesn't seem to work in C#, but that's nevertheless the way I'd like to construct my code.

```
public class C
{
    public static object[] GetAttrs(Type type, string propertyName)
    {
        return type.GetProperty(propertyName).GetCustomAttributes(true);
    }
}

public class A
{
    [Attribute1(Name="myAttributeName")]
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    // Through an attribute definition
    // Unfortunately, passing variable to attrs not supported
    // so this does not work
    [Attribute2(C.GetAttrs(typeof(A), nameof(A.Property1)))]
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    // In a method
    public void method()
    {
        var attrs = C.GetAttrs(typeof(A), nameof(A.Property1));
    }
}
```

However, it feels tedious to pass references to both the class and property, when syntactically, `A.Property1` contains information about both - something a compiler should be able to draw information from. Therefore, I wonder if any such operator exists today, or if there are any other ideas on how this functionality could be achieved?

EDIT: I just thought about the `B.Property2` attribute definition one more time and thought that it should still be possible to get this working, since I think attributes are constant. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: attributes accept only simple numeric types (not Decimal), strings and types. So you cant pass function invokation there. the reason for that is that they should be resolvable at compilation time

Comment: *when syntactically, A.Property1 contains information about both* this is false, `nameof(A.Property1)` is just a string with *Property1* value

Comment: Well, I don't know how to phrase it, then. Logically, the string `A.Property1` contains all information about which object and property I'm interested in. But my knowledge of compilers is limited, so maybe it would be impossible for the C# compiler to get this information out. I am definitely aware of your logic and see where you're coming from, anyways!

Comment: I totally get what you mean, but I think this is just the way it works, and there is nothing we could do about it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no default operator for such case, but you could implement something similar. Code to extract value from A.Property1 attribute is in Main function

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp16
{
    public class CustomAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string Name { get; }

        public CustomAttribute(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }

    public class ReferenceAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string PropertyName { get; }
        public Type Type { get; }

        public ReferenceAttribute(Type type, string propertyName)
        {
            Type = type;
            PropertyName = propertyName;
        }
    }

    public class A
    {
        [Custom("text")]
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class B
    {
        [Reference(typeof(A), nameof(A.Property1))]
        public string Property { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var referenceAttribute = typeof(B).GetProperty(nameof(B.Property))
                .GetCustomAttribute<ReferenceAttribute>();

            var customAttribute = referenceAttribute.Type.GetProperty(referenceAttribute.PropertyName)
                .GetCustomAttribute<CustomAttribute>();

            Console.WriteLine(customAttribute.Name);
        }
    }
}
```